# iOS designated initializer issues during assignment

Tags: ios, iphone, exception

I have three properties defined in my header file as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *forCount;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *againstCount;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *neutralCount;
```

In my .m file I have then being synthesized using:

```
@synthesize forCount = _forCount;
@synthesize againstCount = _againstCount;
@synthesize neutralCount = _neutralCount;
```

My designated initializer is defined as:

```
- (id)initWithCounts:(NSNumber *)forInitCount
       againstCount:(NSNumber *)againstInitCount
       neutralCount:(NSNumber *)neutralInitCount
{
    NSLog(@"entering chartView initialization");

    NSLog(@"chartView initialization. data being sent: forCount:%@, againstCount:%@, neutralCount: %@",forInitCount,againstInitCount,neutralInitCount);

    if (self = [super init]) {

        [self setForCount:forInitCount];
        [self setAgainstCount:againstInitCount];
        [self setNeutralCount:neutralInitCount];

    }

    NSLog(@"chartView initialization. forCount:%@, againstCount:%@, neutralCount: %@",self.forCount,self.againstCount,self.neutralCount);

    [self setup];
    return self;
}
```

I'm drawing charts in the view in setup.

The assignment to the properties doesn't seem to be working. This is what my log looks like:

```
2013-11-21 03:13:20.897 testProj[4744:70b] entering chartView initialization
2013-11-21 03:13:20.897 testProj[4744:70b] chartView initialization. data being sent: forCount:10, againstCount:1, neutralCount: 5
2013-11-21 03:13:20.931 testProj[4744:70b] ChartView forCount: (null), againstCount: (null), neutralCount: (null)
2013-11-21 03:13:20.933 testProj[4744:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

Any idea why the properties still remain as `(null)`?

Commenting out the [self setup] method also leads to the same `(null)` assignment. - Hence, I can rule out the setup method acting up.

I'm calling the method like so:

```
 NSLog(@"chartViewAtIndex about to be called. forCount:%@, againstCount:%@ and neutralCount:%@",self.forVotes[index],self.againstVotes[index],self.neutralVotes[index]);

ChartView *chartView = [[ChartView alloc]initWithCounts:self.forVotes[index] againstCount:self.againstVotes[index] neutralCount:self.neutralVotes[index]];
```

The log shows:

```
2013-11-21 09:43:46.551 testProj[5284:70b] chartViewAtIndex about to be called. forCount:10, againstCount:1 and neutralCount:5
```

A break statement after assignment, just before the NSLog line reveals that the assignment is correct:

```
_forCount   __NSCFNumber *  (int)10 0xb0000000000000a2
_againstCount   __NSCFNumber *  (int)1  0xb000000000000012
_neutralCount   __NSCFNumber *  (int)5  0xb000000000000052
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for `setup` method? Also code for calling method `initWithCounts:againstCount:neutralCount:`?

Comment: There is something U R not telling us, I made a copy of your code ind it works, show us the calling method, the allocation of your custom object

Comment: debug this 3 `[self setForCount:forInitCount];
        [self setAgainstCount:againstInitCount];
        [self setNeutralCount:neutralInitCount];` and see what happens in them. Write back the logs. Are they setting the values of `forCount, againstCount, neutralCount`?

Comment: Works fine here. Just called the method by sending in the 3 values as [NSNumber numberWithInt:]

Comment: what is super ? NSObject or some faillible class ?

Comment: This gets even weirder. I basically, created a new project and after importing my classes the code works. I still have the old project stored - puzzled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

For anyone else have initialization issues double check what [super init] is going to do. In my case, I had another initializer which was being called and hence it messed things up. The other initializer called [self setup] without assigning values and hence the crash.